# Estimating the non- parametric conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, kde, scipy, numpy

I have a set of observation from two parameters, let say $x$ and $y$ and then I want to make the conditional probability of $x$ for the given $y$, $p(x|y)$. So first I use `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` to obtain the joint probability distribution of $p(x,y)$ and use **normalized histogram** and **one dimensional interpolation** to obtain $p(y)$ and then in the grid points of $x$ and $y$ plane, I compute $\frac{p(x,y)}{p(y)}$ in order to get $p(x|y)$. I also want to measure cumulative distribution of the conditional probability in the grids. Is it the correct approach to estimate the ***conditional probability*** or there are other efficient and faster approaches?